# Jquery acts differently in production GAE

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine

I implemented a simple dialog form using JQuery on GAE.  It works perfectly on my local machine but when I upload to app engine, the response function never fires.  Is this a restriction on app engine, or am I doing something wrong?

```
$("span.competing").click(function() {
    $.get("jsonBands.jsp", {
        bandId: $(this).attr("id")
    }, function(data) { // <---- this never fires
        $("#bandNamePopUp").html(data.bandName);
        $("#bandInfoPopUp").html(data.bandBio);
        $("#bandPicturePopUp").attr("src", data.image);
        $("#band-summary-dialog").dialog("open");
    }, "json");
});
```

I tried to debug with firebug. I put a break point at the same line as my comment.  On the local host the breakpoint hits and stops.  On the live app the break point never hits.

Comment: No errors.  Works fine on the local host.  Should be the same code, I don't get it.

Comment: Try manually retrieving jsonBands.jsp -- what do you get?

Comment: that was the problem, the data on the local side was good but on production there were quotes that I didn't escape.  If you post an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: The problem, for posterity, is that the function in question is a success function - so it only gets invoked if the server-side request returned a 200.

Comment: it was returning 200, just not a valid json response, that's why it was hard to catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-posted from my comment:

> Try manually retrieving jsonBands.jsp -- what do you get?

It's generally unlikely that your Javascript itself would stop working when moving into production, since it's always run client-side ;-)

This was the only noticeable possible point of failure that I saw in your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using GAE-Python and retrieving JSON with jQuery successfully. Try setting the Content-Type header to "application/json".